# Coloring the appropriate item from the list after clicking. [Next Js]

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to create a function that will color the hearts when clicked.

I wrote a function that prints out elements for me, but when I click on any heart, it colors them all.

Where could the problem be?

My code:

```
const \[userInput, setUserInput\] = useState("");
const \[list, setList\] = useState(\[\]);
const \[hearth, setHearth\] = useState(false);
const \[active, setActive\] = useState(-1);

const handleChange = (e) =\> {
e.preventDefault();
setUserInput(e.target.value);
};

const handleSubmit = (e) =\> {
e.preventDefault();
setList(\[userInput, ...list\]);
setUserInput("");
};

const wishList = (e) =\> {
setHearth(!hearth);
};

useEffect(() =\> {}, \[userInput, list\]);

return (
\<div className="favMusic"\>
<h1>FavMusicList</h1>
\<form\>
\<input value={userInput} onChange={handleChange} type="text" /\>
\<button onClick={handleSubmit}\>Submit\</button\>
\</form\>

      <ul className="favMusic__list">
        {list.map((i, idx) => {
          console.log(idx);
    
          return (
            <li key={idx}>
              {i}{" "}
              <div
                id={idx}
                onClick={() => wishList(idx)}
                className={"hearth" + " " + (hearth ? "true" : "false")}>
                <AiOutlineHeart
                
                />
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I have tried all possible ways from setState to others found on the net but I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: because all of them are listening to the same variable hearth

Comment: I would recommend that  each heart should manage its own state. Give the active state on click to the child heart component and remove it from the parent component. That is why they are all active or inactive right now. The parent is managing one state object and passing that state to each child object. So if you move the active state to the child object, then each can manage their own state and will be individual from the other child objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-ymquqj?file=pages/index.js).

Assuming your state data is an array of items, each with its own boolean property indicating whether it's been "liked" by the user:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    liked: true,
    title: 'ListItem 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    liked: false,
    title: 'ListItem 2',
  },
// ...
]
```

Then in your click handler, you'd want to loop over each of the objects to find the item with the corresponding id to change just the boolean property for that one item.  For example:

```js
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    const newLikes = items.map((item) => {
      // check the current element's id against the 
      // id passed to the handler
      if (item.id === id) {
        // if it matches, update the liked property
        // and return the modified object
        return { ...item, liked: !item.liked };
      }
      // if it doesn't match, just return the
      // original object
      return item;
    });
    // update state with the new data
    setItems(newLikes);
  };
```